# UIWebView custom header not finishing loading?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, custom-headers

I have a `UIWebView` in my application. It loads most of the pages and the function `webViewDidFinishLoad` gets called when the loading finishes. But i am trying to add custom header in web-view request, pages loading doesn't finished. The URL requested was https, and has no valid certificate.

I am Using `NSURLConnection`, for communicate with a self-signed server, as we have the ability to control the authentication through the extra delegate methods which are not available to a `UIWebView`. So using `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` we can authenticate against the self signed server.

In these cases neither

```
-  (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView nor 
-  (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError
```

is getting called.

What could be the possible cause of this?

Best Regards,
Gison

Comment: Where is your code? Is the web view starting its load?

Comment: Web view started loading, but not finishes.